# DISTINCT TOP 10 on a Single Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL statement is not working, and I am not sure how to correct it:

```
select
    a0.TEST as TEST,
    count(DISTINCT TOP 10 a0.TEST_CLMN) as CC
from 
    dbo.TESTING a0
group by 
    TEST
```

If I remove TOP 10 it returns results, else I get

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.

Is it possible to apply `DISTINCT` and `TOP 10` on a single column ?

EDIT:
DOES TOP 10 have to be after select ?

Comment: That's not how `DISTINCT` works.  It doesn't apply to a single column - it applies to the entire resultset.  Please include sample data and a desired result.  I can't tell at all what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense. What do you try to accomplish? [edit] your question to include sample data (DDL+DML, please) and desired results.

Comment: @Siyual `COUNT(DISTINCT Column)` does work like that - it counts the number of distinct values in a column.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, that is true, but that's not at all how I interpreted their question.

Comment: I just have to debug this, I am not sure what the author tried to accomplish but seems unlogical

Comment: How could you have inherited code that simply doesn't work? You are right that the code is not logical.

Comment: So TOP 10  must be after  select ?

Comment: Top w/o an order by never makes sense.    Perhaps a row number needs to be assigned to each partitioned test and only count distinct values within the top 10 rows of each test?  Really depends on the requirement here. and it doesn't seem like you know what the requirement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I understand from your query:
You want to get the number of distinct values of `test_clmn` for each `test`, but if there are more than 10 distinct values you want to get just 10 as the count result.

If that's true, you can probably do something like this:

```
SELECT  test, 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT test_clmn) > 10 THEN
            10
        ELSE
            COUNT(DISTINCT test_clmn)
        END As CountDistinct
FROM dbo.testing
GROUP BY test
```

However, as I wrote in the comments to the question - the query as posted doesn't make much sense, so this is only a guess.

Comment: I agree with your logic, I think this is the best result expect based on the query

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to count distinct values and get the top 10 results from your groups:

```
select top 10
  a0.test,
  count(distinct a0.test_clmn) as cc
from dbo.testing a0
group by a0.test
order by cc desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select distinct top 10 a0.TEST as TEST
from dbo.TESTING a0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
select TOP 10
    a0.TEST as TEST,
    count(DISTINCT a0.TEST_CLMN) as CC
from 
    dbo.TESTING a0
group by 
    TEST
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'. I guess top must be after select